# Elasticsearch sorting with from/size

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I have to use sorting along with from and size parameters in the elastic search query.

I am querying elastic search with 0 to 100 records and then 101 to 200 records and then 201 to 300 records.  I have to sort the entire set with salary field.

will the from/size support sorting for the whole set.

Will it sort the whole set and takes 100 records at a time?

Thanks,

Comment: update with your search query so we see what you have done so far!

Comment: Sort is done globally , not just on the results you fetch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sort will happen first, and then the size will take records 100-200 AFTER it's been sorted.

Comment: @jhilden What if sort parameter is not present in paginated query? Can we still be sure that all results were returned (of course after all pages are fetched) ?

Comment: you are not required to specify a sort.  If you're going to be fetching all records you should use a Scroll & Scan instead of paging.